# Can we prevent a cell of excel sheet from delete operation?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am creating a excel sheet from java program and user can update the excel sheet. I will read the same excel file from another program.

I want to restrict a user from deleting a cell from excel sheet. Can I achieve the same in Java? I searched over internet but I didn't get any solution for this.

The same thing may possible using VBA scripts but I want solution for this in java.

Answer (score 2):

Make the sheet-protection is what you are looking for, see [Sheet.protectSheet()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#protectSheet%28java.lang.String%29):

```
    Workbook wb = ...
    Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet();
    assertFalse(sheet.getProtect());

    sheet.protectSheet("Test");  
    assertTrue(sheet.getProtect());

    sheet.protectSheet(null);
    assertFalse(sheet.getProtect());
    wb.close();
```

Comment: You are passing password for the sheet. If user wants to delete a cell and if correct password will be given then he will be able to delete ryt?

Comment: Yes, I think that is how the "protection" feature works in Excel.

Comment: Thanks for your response :)